# phalcon caching css js

Tags: css, caching, phalcon

running phalcon on vagrant centos 7 with php7 and apache. 
it doesn't update css or js when I change it. js throws `Invalid or unexpected token` when I add anything. It's not encoding problem. I think It's caching and can't figure out how to disable it. same project works on different machine

Answer (score 0):

I use Phalcon and I love it, but the caching does get annoying. I haven't yet figured out how to disable caching, but I can help with the caching problem. It took me a while to figure this out too.

Anyways, to the point!

`$this->assets->addCss("public/css/style.css");` This is what I use

or you might use this:

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/project/public/css/style.css" />`

or even this:

`$this->tag->stylesheetLink("public/css/style.css");`

But that doesn't matter how you output the css. What matter is the link. you see that `public` folder? Yeah, remove that and it's forwarding slash. and it'll look like this URL `css/style.css` So you can switch this `public` folder on and off to switch between the cached version of your `css` or `js` files.

so if your page isn't updating as you update the files, then switch to see which loads the changes:

`$this->assets->addCss("css/style.css");`

just switch between these two urls until you got the non-cached file.

`$this->assets->addCss("public/css/style.css");`

If you have the phalcon's `.htaccess` files, then you'll have no problem doing this. I hope this helped!